# Convert 14 digit integer to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, integer

I need your support to convert integer: `20160513225918`

I wanted like : `2016-05-13 22:59:18`

thank you.

Comment: What format is that number? (Aka how do you know that 20160513225918 is  2016-05-13 22:59:18)?

Comment: 20160513225918 will not fit in an int ... via a string: `DateTime.ParseExact("20160513225918", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null)`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What type is your original number? String, long...?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use basic arithmetic for this, **no string parsing necessary**

```cs
var value = 20160513225918;

return new DateTime(
    (int)(value / 10000000000),
    (int)(value / 100000000 % 100),
    (int)(value / 1000000 % 100),
    (int)(value / 10000 % 100),
    (int)(value / 100 % 100),
    (int)(value % 100));
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oUH5WK)

Answer (score -1):

**Important Point:** First thing that your value does not fit in the integer datatype, because value gets overflow. `Int` accepts value within **-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647**. Try to store that value in `long`

When you try `DateTime.ParseExact()` it will throw an error **input string was not recognized as a valid datetime**

So you can extract the each individual part using `substring`

Like this

```
long data = 20160513225918;
int year = int.Parse(data.ToString().Substring(0, 4));
int month = int.Parse(data.ToString().Substring(4, 2));
int day = int.Parse(data.ToString().Substring(6, 2));
int hour = int.Parse(data.ToString().Substring(8, 2));
int minute = int.Parse(data.ToString().Substring(10, 2));
int second = int.Parse(data.ToString().Substring(12, 2));

//bellow line will get you "2016-05-13 22:59:18"
var date = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

1. The first parameter inside Substring is **start index**
2. The second parameter inside Substring is **length**

Comment: that claim: `When you try DateTime.ParseExact() it will throw an error input string was not recognized as a valid datetime` seems wrong, could you clarifiy it? DateTime.ParseExact would work if the "exact" format is being used (as shown in a comment below the question)

Comment: Yes I tried to pass the format to `DateTime.ParseExact()` it gets an error **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: Then you passed the wrong format string.

Comment: @CodeCaster can you specify the format?